# Is there a way to display text over a background for an actionbar?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I would like to display a text over a background for each menu item in my actionBar, 
how would I achieve this?  or can you kindly direct me to some examples or resource?

Comment: I added Android and Java tags, assuming that was what you meant...

Comment: that is correct this is for android.

Comment: any ideas on how to achieve what I'm asking?